# NSURLSession send GET request even if I set POST in HTTPMethod

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, nsurlsession

i'm trying to send a POST request to my server with the following code:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObj = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:defaultConfigObj];

//NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.myserver.com/page.aspx"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://10.47.72.40/test/page.aspx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:10.10f];
NSString *params = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data=%@&UserMail=%@",
                    InfoDictionary[@"ID"],
                    arrDatosMail[0]
                    ];

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@ error:%@", response, error);

    if(error == nil){
        NSString *textRepsonse = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Data: %@", textRepsonse);


    }
}];
```

So, when a try with the local IP, it works fine (the server receives the POST request), but when I change the remote IP (with de www.myserver.com/page.aspx) the page receives the request with GET method, i don't know why :(,

What i'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you checking the HTTP method that's being used?

Comment: Did you get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem. Request will be sent as POST.
I would recommend to use proxy to debug what is send exactly. On Mac Charles proxy is good one.

[Charles proxy web site](http://www.charlesproxy.com)